# the condition set for session when public user visiting without login

Tags: php

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

$db = mysql_select_db("tumy", $connection);
session_start();

$user_check=$_SESSION['username'];

$ses_sql=mysql_query("select username from customer where   username='$user_check'", $connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session =$row['username'];
//if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
//header('Location: homepage.php');
//}

?>
```

May I know is there need to set any condition when public visiting my website?
Because it shows

```
undefined index: username in $user_check.
```

When the header `Location: homepage.php`, it direct come out with blank page.

So may I know the solution for it?

Comment: **session_start();** must be the first line .

Comment: As CodeLove suggested already. Also store the values inside session object to access them further after LOG IN .

Comment: Where are you setting your $_SESSION['username']?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a little help with the logic / process.  This would be my suggested method using your code:

```
// always start this first
session_start();

// check for logged-in user..
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){

    // ..and redirect if necessary
    header('Location: homepage.php');
    exit;

} else {

    // only do a db connection if needed
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    $db = mysql_select_db("tumy", $connection);

    $user_check = $_SESSION['username'];

    $ses_sql=mysql_query("select username from customer where   username='$user_check'", $connection);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);

    if($row['username'] != ''){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    }

    // redirect if required.. ..or continue

}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I include this session in my homepage and I use $login_session to set "logout.php" when the user is login.
<?php include('session1.php');
?><ul id="navigations">
     <li><a href="homepage.php">HOME</a></li>
     <li> <a href="restaurant.php">RESTAURANTS</a></li>
     <li><a href="rating.php">CUSTOMER FEEDBACK</a></li>
     <li><a href="userprofile.php">USER PROFILE</a></li>
     <?php if(isset($login_session)) {
 echo "<li><a href='logout.php'>LOGOUT</a></li>";
} else {
 echo "<li><a href='Log In.php'>LOGIN</a></li>"; } ?>
         </ul>

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();  must be on top of the file.
```

and you can use the condition

```
$user_check = isset($_SESSION['username'])?$_SESSION['username']:"";
```